# Send and receive over serial port doesn't work

Tags: c#, terminal, serial-port

I am new at programming.

I am making a terminal program for some testing, the program has to send and receive data over serial-null modem. I found an example at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

But I cant get it to work.  Here is what I have now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Terminal_0._0._0._2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string name;
            string message;
            StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

            // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
            SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();

            // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM8";
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            // Set the read/write timeouts
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.Open();
            var _continue = true;
            readThread.Start();

            Console.Write("Name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

            while (_continue)
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();

                if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
                {
                    _continue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _serialPort.WriteLine(
                        String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
                }
            }

            readThread.Join();
            _serialPort.Close();
        }



    }
    public static void Read()
        {
            while (_continue)
            {
                try
                {
                    string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }
            }
        }
}
```

I get this error: 
Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
on line: 66
Column: 19

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you would need a better title of the question ..

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? "I can't get it to work" gives us nothing to work with.

Comment: What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: Thanks for updating the titel, i have added the error i get and where visual studio say it is.

Comment: @BenjaminKarlog -  What statement is on line 66.

Comment: @dbasnett it says that it is the "void"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there may be several things causing it not to work.
First of all, the Read method is outside the Program scope, resulting in it not working. 
Secondly, moving it inside won't work either, until you also make "_continue" and "_serialPort" fields (outside methods).

Reworked code (removed redundant 'using' statements):

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Terminal_0._0._0._2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool _continue;
        private static SerialPort _serialPort;

        public static void Main()
        {
            string name;
            string message;
            StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            var readThread = new Thread(Read);

            // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
            _serialPort = new SerialPort
                {
                    PortName = "COM8",
                    BaudRate = 115200,
                    Parity = Parity.None,
                    DataBits = 8,
                    StopBits = StopBits.One,
                    Handshake = Handshake.None,
                    ReadTimeout = 500,
                    WriteTimeout = 500
                };

            // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.

            // Set the read/write timeouts

            _serialPort.Open();
            _continue = true;
            readThread.Start();

            Console.Write("Name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

            while (_continue)
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();

                if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
                {
                    _continue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _serialPort.WriteLine(
                        String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
                }
            }

            readThread.Join();
            _serialPort.Close();
        }

        public static void Read()
        {
            while (_continue)
            {
                try
                {
                    string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                catch (TimeoutException) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I don't have any serial devices, I can't test it, but the compiler compiled it without errors.

Thanks
Bjarke